# How to create subcomponents using Jira REST API

Tags: json, components, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to add subcomponents to existing components using Jira REST API.

Currently, I have managed to add components to specific project with POST to *rest/api/latest/component* with the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "name": "Component 1",
    "description": "This is a JIRA component",
    "leadUserName": "me",
    "assigneeType": "PROJECT_LEAD",
    "isAssigneeTypeValid": false,
    "project": "My_project"
}
```

Is there any way to specify in which component I want the new one to be placed, or in other words - to create a subcomponent? I had a look at the Jira REST API documentation, but could not find what field needs to be included in the JSON data to make it a subcomponent of existing one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Jira doesn't support subcomponents. There may be plugins that add this feature. I usually just name the components so that they all start with the same string, e.g.

foo bar

foo baz

goo

hoo

Comment: Thank you. In my Jira this is available, as I have managed to create a Components hierarchy from Configuration Management -> Subcomponents. I wanted to find a way to add a component to a specific level in the hierarchy, without using the GUI. Did this by hand however, was not a big deal.